# Greek letters from Octave pdf documents are displayed as vertical lines in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, octave

I exported an octave plot to a pdf-document and included it in a LaTeX document. The greek letters in the pdf-file are displayed as vertical lines in the output of the LaTeX document (see image below).
[image: GreekLetters]
However, when I open the document with my browser, it's fine:
[image: GreekLettersFine]
Here is the code of the octave plot:

```
xlabel('\Omega');
```

And here is the code of the LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{Omega.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Update: There seems to be an issue with specific letters only. Lower case letters are displayed correctly across the board and upper case greek letters are sometimes displayed correctly (for example Gamma). Delta however is displayed as the sign for the empty set.
Once again, everything is displayed correctly when opening the document in the browser. This is what the broken version looks like:
[image: UpperLower]

Comment: Try to place it inside dollar signs ... (may be I am wrong but you have nothing to lose)

Comment: Placing it inside dollar signs just adds dollar sings in the pdf.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Have you tried viewing the pdf output of latex in another viewer?

Comment: Yes, I did. As I wrote, when opening the document in the browser, it is displayed correctly.

Comment: can we see the PDF?

Comment: Try if it works if you add `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` to your latex document.

Comment: Adding this command to the header doesn't change anything.